# AWS S3 upload progress callback not being fired

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am trying to get back progress report of my file upload to AWS S3 from a react native app. As you can see I am listening for the `httpUploadProgress` event and trying to print the progress. But this callback function is not being called. What am I missing here?

```
    AWS.config.update({
       region: AWS_REGION,
       accessKeyId: user.credentials.AccessKeyId,
       secretAccessKey: user.credentials.SecretKey,
       sessionToken: user.credentials.SessionToken
    });
    const imageArrayBuffer = decode(image.data);
    const s3 = new AWS.S3();
    const params = {
        Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
        Key: photoKey,
        Body: imageArrayBuffer,
        ContentType: image.type
    };

    s3
        .upload(params)
        .on('httpUploadProgress', function(evt) {
            console.log(
                'Uploaded :: ' + parseInt(evt.loaded * 100 / evt.total) + '%'
            );
        })
        .send(function(err, data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? If evt.total is 0, you have a divide by zero error. evt.total can be undefined depending on the stream type. Also upload() takes a function(err, data) as the second parameter.

Comment: Did it actually upload the file? Was it tiny?

Comment: @JohnHanley The function doesn't even get called so there is no error showing up.

Comment: @jarmod Yes the file is uploaded. I tried it with 3mb file.

Comment: I do see the progress callback when uploading various sizes via Buffer or ReadableStream options. I tried files from 10KB to 30MB and all resulted in at least one callback (at 100%). Is your AWS SDK up to date?

Comment: I am now thinking it might have something to do with react native implementation of xhr.

Comment: Don't sweat it, this is not the right solution anyway. `httpUploadProgress` will only get called once. It's not what you think. This only reports the completion of individual parts in a multi-part upload.

Comment: I am facing the exact same issue. Did you find a solution?